# Can Python have an input before a string on the same line? If so, how?

Tags: python

Sorry if my question is worded wrong, but I'm trying to achieve something like:

```
{text} {input}                                                  {more text}
```

like in this image:
[image of ZSH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnaaq.png)

I know this can be done by going up a line (not sure how though), but I like it more that the text on the right is already there.

Comment: You'll need to know the current width of (terminal) window. But have a look at the [curses module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html).

Comment: As an aside: usually, I find the trouble of something like this is not worth it.

Comment: I feel this question is wrongly closed. The dupe adds `{more text}` after pressing enter. OP mentioned **I like it more that the text on the right is already there.**

Comment: You can use return carriage(`\r`) here. Try this `input("                              time\r$ ")`. [Try it online](https://replit.com/@Ch3seR/ReturnCarriage#main.py)